# How to show specific image from the database when doing a edit function in a vue component?

Tags: laravel, forms, vue.js, modal-dialog, vue-component

I'm making a SPA using laravel and vue. I dont know how to show the specific image of the `news` when Im making a update/edit function. In laravel I know how to do it by using a `@foreach` and `asset` something like that. But in the vue component I'm having a hard time figuring it out. I'm using the `vform` package btw so that my form is filled automatically with the data which I want to edit but the my problem is how to show the image like i filled the text field by using `fill` function from the `vform` package. What do I need to do in order to fix my problem?

[image]
News.vue

```
             <!-- show/edit modal extra large -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="editNews" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                               <div class="modal-header">
                                  <h4> <strong>Edit</strong> </h4>
                               </div>
                               <div class="modal-body">
                                            <!-- Vform -->
                                  <form @submit.prevent="updateNews()">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>News Title</label>
                                    <input
                                    v-model="form.title"
                                    type="text" name="title"
                                    placeholder="Title"
                                    class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('title') }">
                                    <has-error :form="form" field="title"></has-error>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Subtitle</label>
                                    <input
                                    v-model="form.subtitle"
                                    type="text"
                                    name="subtitle"
                                    placeholder="Subtitle"
                                    class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('subtitle') }">
                                    <has-error :form="form" field="subtitle"></has-error>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>News Content</label>
                                    <textarea
                                    v-model="form.body"
                                    type="text"
                                    name="body"
                                    placeholder="News Content"
                                    class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('body') }">
                                    </textarea>
                                    <has-error :form="form" field="body"></has-error>
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Picture</label>
                                    <input type="file" id="image" @change="addImage"
                                    class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('image') }">
                                    <has-error :form="form" field="image"></has-error>
                                    </div>

                                     <div>
                                     <h4>Currently Displayed News Image</h4>

                                    </div>



                        <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit Changes</button>
                         </div>
                        </form>
                        <!-- vform -->
                               </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <!-- modal edit/show -->
```

The script below the News.vue

```
<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return{
                editmode:false,
                news: {},
                form: new Form({
                    id:"",
                    title: "",
                    subtitle:"",
                    body:"",
                    image:"",
                    postedby:""
                })
            }
        },

        methods: {
            loadNews(){
                axios.get('api/news')
                    .then(({data}) => (this.news = data))
            },
            createNews(){
                //  console.log('hello')
                this.$Progress.start()
                this.form.post("api/news")
                    .then(()=>{
                         $("#addNews").modal("hide")
                         $(".modal-backdrop").remove()
                        swal.fire("Created!", "", "success")
                         Fire.$emit("UpdateTable");
                    })
                this.$Progress.finish()
            },
            addImage(e){
                // console.log(e.target.files[0])
                var fileReader = new FileReader()
                fileReader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0])
                fileReader.onload = (e) => {
                    this.form.image = e.target.result
                }
                // console.log(this.form)
            },
            editForm(newsdata){
             //shows the modal for edit and fills the data in it.

                this.editmode = true
                this.form.reset()
                $('#editNews').modal('show')
                this.form.fill(newsdata)
            },
            updateNews(){
            //update the news based on the modal inputs (not working need few codes in controller @update method)
                this.form.put('api/news/' + this.form.id)
                    .then(()=>{
                        $('#editNews').modal('hide')
                        $(".modal-backdrop").remove()
                        swal.fire("Updated!", "", "success")
                        Fire.$emit('UpdateTable')
                        this.$Progress.finish()
                    })
            },
        },

        created() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
            this.loadNews();

            Fire.$on("UpdateTable",()=>{
                this.loadNews();
            })
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this for img:

```
<img src="" id="imagepreview">
```

Then you can simply do:

```
$('#imagepreview').attr('src', "IMAGEDIRECTORYHERE" + newsdata.image);
```

Comment: It now reads the image from the directory sir but it throws me and error of `GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/news/FATqHG9c7yr2DdNO.jpg 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Are your images located within the "public/news/" folder? If it is then doing $('#imagepreview').attr('src', "news/" + newsdata.image); should work

Comment: no sir. My image directory is `public/img/news` and I wrote this code ` $('#imagepreview').attr('src', "public/img/news/" + newsdata.image)` and still gets me an 404 error not found

Comment: remove the public and just put "img/news/"

Comment: Thank you sir. Your answer is right. Thanks a lot :)